# How to use rsync <3.0 to specify a relative upload path, generate subfolders

Tags: ftp, rsync, sftp

I am writing a script where I'd like to upload individual files and have the folder structure automatically generated like mkdir -p but I can't get rsync 2.6.9 (both) to cooperate.

It looks like rsync is making only one level of folders, otherwise erroring.

I'm trying to reproduce handy `ncftpput -C -R -m remote-host local-path-name remote-path-name` actions ( ncftp's Recursive mode; copy whole directory trees + Attempt to make the remote destination directory before copying.).

Possible?

**My Attempts:**

```
rsync -av -e ssh /home/gitrepos/www/board/httpdocs/B/C/delete_snippet.processor.php user@testboard.org:/var/www/vhosts/testboard.org/httpdocs/B/C/delete_snippet.processor.php
```

**returns:**

> rsync: push_dir#3
>   "/var/www/vhosts/testboard.org/httpdocs/B/C"
>   failed: No such file or directory (2)

```
rsync -av -e ssh /home/gitrepos/www/board/httpdocs/B/C/delete_snippet.processor.php user@testboard.org:/var/www/vhosts/testboard.org/httpdocs/
```

**works, creates httpdocs, but without the B/C structure.**

```
rsync -advR -e ssh -v /home/gitrepos/www/board/httpdocs/B/C/delete_snippet.processor.php user@testboard.org:/var/www/vhosts/testboard.org/httpdocs/
```

**works but recreates the entire /home/gitrepos... structure on the server.**

*permissions are set 777 and owned by user.*

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using rsync 2.6.7 or later you can try the dot slash method after the httpdocs for limiting the directories. Try this:

```
rsync -advR -e ssh -v /home/gitrepos/www/board/httpdocs/./B/C/delete_snippet.processor.php user@testboard.org:/var/www/vhosts/testboard.org/httpdocs/
```

Comment: Hey it works! The internet version of the manual made it sound like that was 3.0+ feature and I didn't see it in my local manfile. I halfheartedly tried but wasn't sure which side it belonged on. Thank you.